# C++ - how to read file save by ofstream::binanry

Tags: c++

Hope you are doing well, I wrote the code to save my txt with number for each line into the binary file named "csdl.bin". Now i would like to read the content from that binary file and show it on the console screen.

**saving binary file from txt file**

```
void saveinbinary()
{
    ifstream in("csdl.txt", ifstream::in);
    ofstream out("csdl.bin", ofstream::binary);
    char temp[255];
    while(in.getline(temp,255)) {
        out.write((char*)temp, sizeof(temp));
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

**reading from binary file:**

```
void readbinary(int *arr, int n)  //i would like to use array to store all number from the binary file
{
    ifstream in("csdl.bin", ifstream::binary);
    in.seekg(0,in.end); 
    long size = in.tellg();
    in.seekg(0);
    n = size/sizeof(arr);
    arr=new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int number;
        in.read((char*)number, sizeof(n));
        arr[i]=number;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    }
}
```

This is content in my txt file:

[image]

[image]
When i run the code, it didn't show anything in my console sreen :(.Can anybody please help look this ?

Comment: Put some print statements (cout) in your code after each line and see what all the values are.  In other words, debug it rather than dumping the broken code here for us.

Comment: `in.read((char*)number, sizeof(n));` What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Ruks , I am trying to get the content from the binary file  then put it into the array by the following line:       arr[i]=number;. But i'm not quite my code is correct. Do you have an alternative ?

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` is 4 or 8, the size of a pointer. It's not the size of the data pointed to, as you appear to expect.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, for a beginner using `cout` is more fundamental and appropriate.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `arr=new int[n];` instead of `std::vector<int> arr{};` and letting the container handle the memory management? See [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and bookmark [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) -- best C++ reference on the net... Please also provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method of writing integers to a binary file is wrong, use this:

```cpp
void saveinbinary() {
    std::ifstream in("csdl.txt", std::ifstream::in);
    std::ofstream out("csdl.bin", std::ofstream::binary);

    int number;
    while (in >> number) // Read a number from the text file and put it inside 'number', ignoring all whitespaces
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&number), sizeof number);

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Your function to read the binary file is also wrong, it should be something along the lines of:

```cpp
void readbinary(int*& arr, size_t& n)
{
    std::ifstream in("csdl.bin", std::ifstream::binary);

    in.seekg(0, in.end); 
    size_t const size = in.tellg();
    in.seekg(0);

    n = size / sizeof *arr;
    arr = new int[n];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&arr[i]), sizeof *arr);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
}
```

Also, make sure to call `delete[]` on the dynamically-allocated pointer after you use this function.